# How to choose InfiniBand or Ethernet programmatically?

Tags: networking, ethernet, infiniband

I need (simple) program which allows to choose what to use to transfer data - Infiniband or Ethernet and switch them in runtime. I searched through InfiniBand docs, google and google/codeseaarch and have found nothing. Please provide program or tips where can I find such information.
EDIT: OS and language of implementation doesn't matter much, although Linux and C are preferred.

Comment: You should probably mention what OS you need to implement this for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IB and Ethernet are different protocols, you use BSD sockets for Ethernet and you use whatever verb API of your preference for IB, e.g. OFED, SDP, etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockets_Direct_Protocol

For convenience you can run Ethernet over IB and you use standard IP routing, interface binding, or IPv6 scoping to choose which interface.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Ethernet over IB, IP over IB is available as well.

```
http://infiniband.sourceforge.net/NW/IPoIB/index.htm
```

The current documentation is:

```
http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/infiniband/ipoib.txt

http://www.openfabrics.org/downloads/OFED/ofed-1.4/OFED-1.4-docs/ipoib_release_notes.txt
```

After binding the IB interface to IP, plain IP sockets are available.